# Change background color of highcharts on hover

Tags: jquery, angularjs, highcharts, background-color

I want to change background color of highchart on hover. For column  , we can do it using state.hover.color . I tried using same for whole chart , but its not giving me expected result.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DeoD/wvhw44uc/2/)

```
 states: {
            hover: {
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'                                                           
            }
         }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please, fix your jsfiddle.

Comment: @456 which color you wanted to change?

Comment: black color .. which is there in background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to toggle the bgColor on `mouseover` and `mouseout` of the the chart using

```
chart.chartBackground.css({
   color: 'white',
});

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        zoomType: 'xy',
        backgroundColor: bg
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                mouseOver: function () {
                    chart.chartBackground.css({
                        color: 'white',
                    });
                },
                mouseOut: function () {
                    chart.chartBackground.css({
                        color: 'red',
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    },

    //other option is the same as it was before.

    }]
});
```

[**Forked Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/m37amhpw/)